# Defining an instance to a restricted a type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working with the following Data Type:

```
data Exp a =
|Const a
|Simetrico (Exp a)
|Mais (Exp a) (Exp a)
|Menos (Exp a) (Exp a)
|Mult (Exp a) (Exp a)
```

but `a` is supposed to be a Numeric type.
I would define `Eq` like this:

```
instance Eq (Exp a) where
         a == b | ... = True
                | otherwise = False
```

but I am saying nowhere that my `a` is a numeric type, so ghci complains, how do I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add a type constraint to the `instance` clause:

```
instance Num a => Eq (Exp a) where
         a == b | ... = True
                | otherwise = False
```

So now you can assume (in the scope of the `instance`) that `a` is an instance of the `Num` typeclass.

Comment: But now I tried doing it with show, and this error popped up:
    • Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the instance declaration at Ficha8.hs:51:10-30
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration
    • In the expression: show a
      In an equation for ‘show’: show (Const a) = show a
      In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Exp a)’

Comment: @DeltaXGamerPT: you can add extra type constraints like `instance (Show a, Num a) => Eq (Exp a) where ...`. But a `show` in an `Eq` instance is rather weird.

Comment: For the `Show (Exp a) where` you probably also should add a type constraint, so `instance Show a => Show (Exp a) where ...`.